# can we use OAUTH /OPenID in corporate LAN where Social network sites are blocked?

Tags: oauth

I am developing one website,in which I have implemented google oauth but when I am trying to run the sample in my office where there is a corporate LAN it is giving an error but the code works fine on my personal machine @ my home.

Also one more question how stackoverflow is using google login I can access this site in office as well using google login.

Please give me suggestions/answers on it do we really need open internet coonection for oAuth/openID.
or will it work in corporate LAN?

Thanks

Comment: For an auth provider whose endpoints are “on the internet” you will of course need access to at least those endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Is it blocked in your office? Or is it behind a proxy? My work puts everything behind a proxy, so I need to account for that in any OAuth code (or connect through our approved gateway).